# How to move a QPushButton inside gridLayout?

Tags: qt, qpushbutton, qgridlayout

I have just tried a simple thing, in designer I created one push button, inside grid layout. The problem is geometry option got disabled in Property box, and I am not able to change the cordinates. In this situation how should I move the push button from its original place if required?

Can somebody help me to achieve this??

Comment: Can you give some examples of what you tried

Comment: ui->m_pushButton->setGeometry(466, 188, 28, 24); this push button is inside gril layout

Comment: Where do you want to move it? You can remove it from the layout and re-add it into the layout(or another layout) somewhere else

Comment: This question lacks the necessary detail. What do you mean by "moving" the widget? Do you want to manage its geometry manually, or do you want to change its row/column?

Answer (score 1):

You can't move or resize a widget inside a layout because its position and its size are managed by the layout. If you want to manage its geometry yourself, do not use a layout.

Answer (score 0):

Qt layouts are designed to help you make scalable user interfaces. For this, moving or resizing the button is usually done by the layout using [`sizeHint()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#sizeHint-prop) and [`sizePolicy()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#sizePolicy-prop).

I would suggest reading up on how to use [layouts](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) and the use of spacers, as this will impact the location and size of your button.

Answer (score 0):

Well I found a solution to that
Break the Layout, arrange the widgets and then set the layout